# Test ssh connection with github shows wrong username

Tags: git, github, ssh

**The problem**

When I test my ssh connection with github using `ssh -T git@github.com`, the username it shows is incorrect -

```
Hi <WRONG USERNAME>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Accordingly, when I try to clone with SSH I get a fatal error saying I don't have permission to access it.

1. Why is this username not showing correctly?
2. How can I change this username?

**What I have tried / checked**

- I have checked my global username for git using `git config --global user.name`.
- I have reset my git credentials in Windows credentials
  manager.
- I have checked that the correct key has been stored on github.

**Other notes**

- I am using Windows 10 operating system.
- I have 3 ssh keys.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing that matters is the private ssh key you're using to identify yourself to github. It looks as if you're using a key that is configured for a user other than the one you want. Try that `ssh` command with an explicit `-i /path/to/key` to make sure you're using the correct key (and probably make sure you have no keys in your ssh agent, if you're running one).

Comment: There's a [Git FAQ entry about using multiple accounts with SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH).

Comment: @larsks using the explicit path shows the correct username (and I deleted keys from ssh agent). Are there edits to my .gitconfig that might be required or changes to my ssh agent to persist the outcome from following the check your provided?

Comment: @bk2204 I followed the steps in this FAQ and updated .ssh/config. The problem above remains.

Comment: The only suggestions I have are the ones from the FAQ (specifically, (a) using a host alias, (b) setting `IdentityFile` for that alias and (c) setting `IdentitiesOnly` for that alias).

Answer (score 2):

> I followed the steps in this FAQ and updated .ssh/config

In order for that config entry to be used (meaning to use the right private key referenced by `IdentityFile`), you need to use the `Host` entry from that `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file in your SSH URL:

```
Host ghuser2
  Hostname github
  User git
  IdentityFile /path/to/user2/private-key
```

Your URL become

```
cd c:\path\to\repo
git remote set-url origin ghuser2:<user2>/<repo.git>
```

Comment: #VonC thankyou for the response. Using your note regarding URL. When I test the SSH connection the correct user name shows -

Comment: #VonC thankyou for the response. Using your note regarding URL. When I test the SSH connection the correct user name shows -

ssh -T git@github.com-<MYUSERNAME>

however, when I got to clone a repo, for example using - 

git clone git@github.com-<MYHOSTNAME>:<MYUSERNAME>/<REPO>.git

I still get the error saying I need to check access rights.

There is a 'know_hosts' file in my ~/.ssh folder - it looks to have a couple of fingerprints in it. Could the contents of this file be causing problems?

Thanks again.

Comment: @eest Again, if you want to test the URL as defined in the config file, the test would be `ssh -T ghuser2`: that would use the right private key, the one associated with the public key added to the right user GitHub profile. `ssh -T ghuser2` becomes a shortcut for `ssh -T -i /path/to/private/key git@github.com`

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I may have confused things with my last comment. In short, I followed what you had outlined and testing connection with github works in that correct user is returned but cloning doesn't. I am unsure as to whyI am still getting an error cloning. If there is some more information I can provide to help diagnose the problem more accurately just let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @eest Yes, what URL are you using when doing the `git clone`? (Adn do you have the latest 2.29.2 Git for Windows?

Comment: `git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git` and
`git@github.com-<username>:<username>/<repo>.git`

Comment: @eest The only SSH URL which has a chance to use the right private key is `git clone ghuser2:<username>/<repo>.git`: if you are not using the `Host` entry in your  `~/.ssh/config` file, you won't be using the associated private key reference by `IdentityFile` in that same file. No `git@` needed: the `User git` in that config file is enough.

Comment: tried git clone `ghuser2:<username>/<repo>.git` without sucess. I am on the latest Git for Windows as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225053/discussion-between-vonc-and-eest).

Answer (score 0):

See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64963923/1256452), and note that if you're using an ssh agent, you can point the configured identity file to the *public* key, so as to select the appropriate public/private keypair to send to GitHub.  The ssh code will then pick up the private key from the agent.

(I've found that when you are *not* using the ssh agent, ssh won't pick up the private key if you point it to the public key file, even if both files are present on the machine, which is sort of annoying.  Another way to put this is: if you do use the agent, `IdentityFile` can be either file, and then you can store *only* the public key on intermediate machines and jump-hosts, which generally is a good idea.  But if you do not use the agent, you obviously must store both public and private keys on the machine, and then `IdentityFile` *must* name the private key of the pair.  Hence, if you *always* use the agent, you can use the same ssh config file everywhere, but if you *sometimes* use the agent, you cannot use the same ssh config file everywhere.)

Comment: Thanks @torek. I have to say your response is a bit over my head but I think there might be a hurdle or two I have to overcome before I implement what you have suggested.